# Web-crawler for unstructured data

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, nlp

Are there any web-crawlers adapted for parsing many unstructured websites (news, articles) and extracting a main block of content from them without previously defined rules?

I mean when I'm parsing a news feed, I want to extract the main content block from each article to do some NLP stuff. I have a lot of websites and it will take forever to look into their **DOM** model and write rules for each of them.

I was trying to use **Scrapy** and get all text without tags and scripts, placed in a body, but it include a lot of un-relevant stuff, like menu items, ad blocks, etc.

```
site_body = selector.xpath('//body').extract_first()
```

But doing NLP over such kind of content will not be very precise.

So is there any other tools or approaches for doing such tasks?

Comment: have you tried a visual approach? I would recommend to check [portia](http://scrapinghub.com/portia/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve this with [pattern matching](http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html). Thereby you annotate  the source of webpage itself and use it as sample that gets matched, and you do not need to write special rules.

For example, if you look in the source of this page, you see:

```
<td class="postcell">
<div>
    <div class="post-text" itemprop="text">

<p>Are there any web-crawlers adapted for parsing many unstructured websites (news, articles) and extracting a main block of content from them without previously defined rules?</p>
```

Then you remove your text and add `{.}` to mark the place as relevant and get:

```
<td class="postcell">
<div>
<div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
{.}
```

(usually you need closing tags as well, but for a single element it is not necessary)

Then you pass that as pattern to Xidel (SO seems to block the default user agent, so it needs to be changed),

```
xidel 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066030/web-crawler-for-unstructured-data' --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Xidel)"  -e '<td class="postcell"><div><div class="post-text" itemprop="text">{.}'
```

and it outputs your text

```
Are there any web-crawlers adapted for parsing many unstructured websites (news, articles) and extracting a main block of content from them without previously defined rules?

I mean when I'm parsing a news feed, I want to extract the main content block from each article to do some NLP stuff. I have a lot of websites and it will take forever to look into their DOM model and write rules for each of them.

I was trying to use Scrapy and get all text without tags and scripts, placed in a body, but it include a lot of un-relevant stuff, like menu items, ad blocks, etc.

site_body = selector.xpath('//body').extract_first()


But doing NLP over such kind of content will not be very precise.

So is there any other tools or approaches for doing such tasks?
```

Comment: Using this approach you still need to define all those **div** blocks and their ID's. Not working for hundreds of websites.

Comment: The idea is, you do not have to write them, just copy them from the webpage. I use this approach for over 200 library webpages

Answer (score 0):

You can use Beautiful Soup inside your `parse()` and `get_text()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'html.parser')

yield {'body': soup.get_text() }
```

You can also manually remove stuff you don't want (if you find that you like some markup e.g. `<H1>`'s or `<b>`'s might be useful signals)

```
# Remove invisible tags
#for i in soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name in ['script', 'link', 'meta']):
#     i.extract()
```

You could do similar thing to whitelist a few tags.